# OpenMP task - know number of tasks in real time

Tags: task, openmp

I would like to know if, in applications parallelized with OpenMP tasks, threads can figure out the number of tasks that were created but not executed yet (presumably hold in the scheduling queue, ready for execution). Is there any such call?

For example, the call

```
get_num_non_executed_tasks()
```

would return the number of tasks that were created so far, but not yet executed;

Comment: Couldn't understand what you need. Mind sharing the code you are attempting to run?

Comment: @Yuval For some reason, part of the text was lost. Can you see the edit, please?

Comment: What do you want such information for? Maybe there is another way to do what you need.

Comment: I want each thread to print a message once it is done with its work but there are still tasks that are yet to execute. This will help me finding out the work (im)balance among threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way in OpenMP to find out how many tasks were created but not yet started.